# JPA repository findBy foreign key for ManyToMany relationship

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following relationship in the data base

[Database Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKjz0.png)

And these are the entities

Apartment.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "apartment")
@Data
public class Apartment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_apartment")
private long id;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
 name = "apartment_facility",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_apartment"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_facility"))

@Column(name = "city")
private String city;

@Column(name = "country")
private String country;
}
```

Facility.java

```
public class Facility {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_facility")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
}
```

My question is how can I create a findBy method in JpaRepository in order to find all Apartments having the required facilities

I'm thinking of the result of this request:

```
api/apartments/findByFacilities?facilities=gym,pool,parking
```

I have tried to do a query but couldn't quite get it. Also tried using Jpa as following

```
List<Apartment> findByFacilities(@RequestParam("facilities") List<String> facilities);
```

But I'm getting the following error. Is there a walkaround?

```
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first code block `List <Facility> facilities = new ArrayList<>();` I guess you forgot to add the code line.

When I look at your link below, I understand that you want to search by the **name** of the facility.

```
api/apartments/findByFacilities?facilities=gym,pool,parking
```

**For this**, your code in `Repository` should be as follows:

```
List<Apartment> findDistinctByFacilitiesNameIn(List<String> facilities);
```

If we don't add **`distinct supported keyword`** here, each record repeats as many as the `facilities` it contains.

If you want to search differently `like, not like, etc.`, See the **`supported keywords inside method names`** table here: **[Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)** document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Seems like the error `Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long]` was because it was expecting a long e.g. api/apartments/1 to get the apartment with id 1. Solved by mapping it to api/apartments/search/
The code you suggested returns an infinite recursion and I don't know why.
It's not mandatory to search by name, its ok to search by facility's id if it's easier.